# How to export the mysql result into csv file using perl script

Tags: mysql, perl, csv

The beloved my perl script code,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
..
.// db connection
..
$sth=$dbh->prepare(" SELECT * FROM Table_nm ") or warn $dbh->errstr;
$sth->execute or die "can't execute the query: $sth1->errstr";

// I want to export the result of mysql query into csv file.
```

Please help. Thanx!

Comment: Please help yourself first. Put your question title in Google and read all the relevant stuff you'll find.

Comment: yes but, I want the more information about the perl script when export into csv.

Comment: Your question contains insufficient information to answer it. Please look at [ask] for how to make a good question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to process the result set prior to outputting it to a csv file, then it would be more efficient to export it directly by adjusting the sql statement.

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM test_table;
```

[13.2.9.1 SELECT ... INTO Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

**EDIT**
To be able to get the header line, you need to add a second select statement which specifies the fields and union that with the other select statement.

Example:

```
mysql> select 'OTOBJID','OTTRANSID'
union
select * into outfile 'd:/test.csv'
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by '"'
from objecttransports;
```

> ```
> D:\>type test.csv
> "OTOBJID","OTTRANSID"
> "0","0"
> "0","1"
> "0","2"
> "0","3"
> "0","4"
> "0","5"
> "1","0"
> "1","1"
> "1","2"
> "1","4"
> "1","5"
> ```

Comment: Hie Thanx but In the above query it will export only rows not the column name how can I achived it?

Comment: See I have comment pls help

Comment: @Pranay See my edited answer which shows how to add the header